# 3D globe from GIS data (QGIS shapefiles or PostGIS)

Tags: qgis, postgis, 3d, globe

I'm looking to create an interactive 3D globe (in Unity 3D in case it matters) that gets its data from a GIS backend. I'm using QGIS as my editor and I can store the data in shapefiles or PostGIS. All my data is vector data, I do not use raster data.

Unlike similar questions, I am not projecting the real world, but an artificial world, so the amount of detail is much lower, and loading the entire dataset into memory, or significant chunks of it, just might be possible.

The same would apply if I'm talking about the real world but I need data visualisation only.

I've found a number of solutions to show a 3D globe (e.g. ol3) or to load GIS data into Unity or convert to 3D models statically (and usually as heightmaps, not as a 3D globe).

I seem to be missing a way to translate GIS data on-the-fly into 3D data, which should be a simple coordinate transformation. PostGIS does not seem to provide an appropriate function.

Some of my data has a height, if that can be converted properly it would also be great.

Comment: What is the 3D coordinate system used by OL/Cesium, and what is the CRS of your data in PostGIS?

Comment: do you want your features draped onto some sort of base terrain? what kind of vectors do you have and what exactly do those features represent? sorry to say that, but in general, if you want more than just to elevate lines/polygons above ground, this is a lot more complex than you might think...if it´s webmaps you want I suggest to have a look at [cesium.js](https://cesiumjs.org/)

Comment: No, I want to make a 3D globe. I can put a blue sphere at the 0,0,0 position as a baseline / ocean, or not. Essentially I have the continents as polygons in QGIS and I want a Unity 3D sphere from that data.